# Conditional formatting with multiple names in list

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, conditional-formatting, regex

Col A2:C15 contain a list of names. I need to enter those names in various combinations into one of 15 other cells on formatted like:

H3 = `John, Steve, Bob, Dan`

Is there a way to use conditional formatting to highlight the cells in A2:C15 based on the list of the names in other cells? I can get it to highlight a cell with just one name, but nothing after the "," is formatted.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A1,TEXTJOIN("|",1,TRIM(SPLIT($H$3, ",")))))
```

[image: 0]